# Any way to hide the Woocommerce tab for WP administrator roles?

Tags: woocommerce

Is there any way to hide the Woocommerce tab for certain accounts even if they have administrator role in Wordpress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way would be to introduce super admin (which would be normal admin like now) and administraror roles and THEN refuse `administraror` role to have access for woocommerce, making it only available to super admin. This should  be doable with 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-access-manager/